# Not able to log back into my Windows machine after Hyper-v installation

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 machine. Recently I have installed Hyper-V 2016 server on my machine. From then whenever I start my system I only see a blue screen with various commands. I do not see any other thing other than that. Now how can I go back to my normal Windows machine?

[See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X8V2.jpg)

Comment: Just by looking at your image, I can see that there are two cmd windows.  Have you tried looking at the other one?

Comment: Looks like you enabled a role that doesn’t have a desktop GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Oh no. I'm sorry to say this but it looks like you installed "Hyper-V Server 2016" over top of your Windows 10 installation.

If all you wanted was to use Hyper-V within Windows 10, then you would've needed Windows 10 Enterprise, Professional, or Education edition and you would've just enabled the Hyper-V role. Home editions of Windows 10 do not have the Hyper-V role available. See: [Enabling Hyper-V on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

What you are seeing is the configuration page for [Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/hyper-v-server-2016) which is a GUI less, hyper-visor only operating system. It has completely replaced your Windows 10 installation. So there is no "going back."

How you proceed next will be dependent on if there is any valuable data that you had on your computer. There is some chance that you managed to install this operating system side-by-side with Windows 10 or somehow saved your data somewhere on your hard drive.

To get back to Windows 10, you'll have to start fresh by wiping the system. The most straight forward way to do this will probably be to attempt to use the computer manufacturer's built in recovery partition - if it is available. But, you didn't mention the make and model of your computer, and many modern Windows 10 systems no longer have an OEM recovery partition. If it is available, you'll find instructions on the manufacturer's website for your specific model of computer.

Apart from that, the most straight forward way to get Windows 10 reinstalled is to just download the media and reinstall it.

If you don't have data:

- From a second Windows computer, create a Windows 10 installation media disk/drive: [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Boot the drive and begin the installation of Windows 10. When you get to the screen prompting you to choose where to install Windows, you will see some hard drive partitions. Click 'Advanced' and delete all of them. Then select the empty space left on the drive and click 'Next.'
- Complete the Windows 10 installation. Once Windows is booted up you should visit the computer manufacturer's website, go to the support/downloads section and download all the drivers available for your specific model of computer.
- Last, download and/or reinstall any applications you were previously using on your computer.

If you have data you want to save:

- The most reliable thing to do would be to boot a Windows or [Linux Live CD/USB](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) drive so that you can get to a familiar "Explorer" style interface.
- Browse the different partitions on your existing hard drive and try to identify your data under a "Users" folder, or under a "Windows.old" folder.
- If you find your data, plug in a USB drive and drag/drop the files to the external drive, then proceed with the Windows 10 reinstall instructions above.
- This is too complicated and has too many variables to post exact instructions for YOUR situation. If you have REALLY important data, you should find someone with the technical skills to help you see if there is any data on your drive before doing anything else.
- I think in this particular scenario, it is highly unlikely you have any data left on the drive. Because you changed from a desktop operating system to a server operating system, there was no "upgrade" performed and likely no data was saved.